# Get rid of ['\n'] in python3 with paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, output, special-characters, paramiko

I've just started to write a monitoring tool in Python 3, and I'm wondering if I can get a 'clear' number output through ssh. I've written this script:

```
import os
import paramiko

command = 'w|grep \"load average\"|grep -v grep|awk {\'print ($10+$11+$12)/3*100\'};'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.123.222.233', username='xxx', password='xxx')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
print (stdout.readlines())
ssh.close()
```

It works fine, except the output is:

```
['22.3333\n']
```

How can I get rid of the `['` and `\n']` and just get the clear number value?

How can I get the result as I see it in PuTTy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.readlines()` returns a *list* of separate lines. In your case there is just one line, you can just extract it by indexing the list, then strip of the whitespace at the end:

```
firstline = stdout.readlines()[0].rstrip()
```

This is still a string, however. If you expected *numbers*, you'd have to convert the string to a `float()`. Since your command line will only ever return **one** line, you may as well just use `.read()` and convert that straight up (no need to strip, as `float()` is tolerant of trailing and leading whitespace):

```
result = float(stdout.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `print(stdout.readlines())` you should iterate over each element in the list that is returned by `stdout.readlines()` and `strip` it, possibly converting it to `float` as well (depends what you are planning to do with this data later).

You can use list comprehension for this:

```
print([float(line.strip()) for line in stdout.readlines()])
```

Note that `strip` will remove whitespaces and new-line chars from both the start and end of the string. If you only want to remove the trailing whitespace/new-line char then you can use `rstrip`, but note that the conversion to `float` may then fail.